# Wallpaper turns into distorted pixels after suspend

Tags: gnome, 64-bit, 14.10, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 64bit on my Lenovo Y500 laptop, and every time the system goes into suspend mode, the wallpaper turns into distorted colors like [image: this] or [image: this] and it's really annoying.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what video driver you use? (Software Center > Edit (menu) > Software Sources > Extra Drivers (tab)

Comment: yeah I use nvidia binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)

Comment: Not a "quality answer", but it might help nevertheless:: often in these occasions, switching to another driver makes a difference.

Comment: sorry, but this is what was written in the tab you mentioned, should I use some other command that will give all the info? if so please tell me what is it?
if it's related to gpu, maybe I have to update the driver?

Comment: doesn't it offer different options like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/drivers.png ?

Comment: oh yes, like this http://imgur.com/bpXk4pZ

Comment: Exactly. You could try one of the others. Occasional minor bugs or incompatibilities occur, changing to another driver often solves the problem.

Comment: I've encountered numerous problems with suspend, so I try not to use it for that reason. I realize that may not fix your problem but it may make you feel better if you discover there isn't a solution.

Comment: Just curious, but did you try :)

Comment: haha damn, that's a relief I guess, I'll just stop using it then.

Comment: sorry, but I haven't, I'd like to use the proprietary driver and usually when I use the other drivers I get more severe problems, like UI disappearing, there's an update to the driver I'm using but I don't know how to install it.

Comment: I truly appreciate your understanding my good intent.  There may be a solution, and if so, I look forward to hearing it.  Come to think of it, I'm going to star your question so that if it is ever solved, I'll learn from it.

Comment: PS:  I should probably add that one of the major improvements in Ubuntu in the past three years or so has been exemplary bootup and shutdown times.  Suspend is much more important with the slowness of windows computers. Here's another tip.  If you tap the power button, (do not hold it down) it brings up a shutdown dialogue.  Pressing enter shuts down the computer properly and quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, the thing is on every bootup, the process gets delayed by a bug in the gpu for like 30 seconds, it writes something about broken pipe and sanity check, then it fixes itself and boot. If this didn't exist I'd probably never suspend, as you said bootup and shutdown times are really low now.

Comment: This solution works it for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1454105/28997

Answer (score 3):

After long time I found a rather practical workaround: The trick is to automatically reset the background upon resume.

To achieve this create a file "**reset-bg-color.sh**", for example in /opt/reset-bg/:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ''
```

The second part is to register this script, so it will be invoked automatically when the computer resumes. In **/lib/systemd/system-sleep** place the second script file, in my case named "**reset-bg.sh**", including the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename "$0")
state=$1
action=$2

function log {
    logger -i -t "$PROGNAME" "$*"
}

log "Running $action $state"

if [[ $state == post ]]; then
    log "WAKE UP"
    exec /opt/reset-bg/reset-bg-color.sh
fi
```

In case you prefer to have a wallpaper reloaded, instead of reset the background color, you can use the following file "**reset-bg-wallpaper.sh**":

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/alex/wallpaper/wallpaper-file.png"
```

and change the exec-statement in **"reset-bg.sh"** to the following:

```
exec /opt/reset-bg/reset-bg-wallpaper.sh
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me, on Gnome 3.30. I think you need to change some keys to it really take effect, like first setting `primary-color '#000001'` and then setting `primary-color '#000000'` afterwards.