# Awake from sleep issues; garbled blocks screen; dual boot laptop

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, suspend, screen, screen-corruption

- **Ubuntu** 18.04.2 LTS
- **Kernel** 4.15.0-45-generic
- **CPU** Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12
- **GPU** GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
- **GNOME** 3.28.2
- **OS type** 64-bit

[image: Garbled screen on wake]

**Description**
Dual boot laptop seems to awake fine with Windows 10 but not Ubuntu.
When booted into Ubuntu and put it to sleep, if left a few hours then woken again, it will show the screen below. This itself goes to black after 10 seconds, presumably due to power saving. I can also still see and move the cursor, but keyboard/mouse clicks do nothing. I end up having to restart the entire laptop to get things going again.

Comment: Your question is well detailed with specs. However it's missing which nVidia driver is being used: proprietary or the open-source Nouveau. Also if nVidia driver you can try a different version number. Also you can try deactivating nVidia driver and using Intel GPU instead for testing suspending / resuming. Finally you can try using **Unity** desktop instead of **Gnome** desktop which also could be the source of the problem.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix re:"Finally you can try using Unity desktop instead of Gnome desktop which also could be the source of the problem.". You don't really mean that, do you? Maybe a faulty GNOME extension... or an incorrect Nvidia driver... the correct version is 418.43... released Feb 22, 2019.

Comment: @heynnema Well I did say ***"Finally"*** and not ***"Firstly"*** :) It's mostly a shot in the dark after all other likely problems have been exhausted.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I usually wouldn't consider making such a major change to "fix" a problem. As I say in my comment... lets troubleshoot extensions and video drivers **first** :-)

Comment: @heynnema Duly noted. I've tried Gnome DE a few times and always ended up throwing it out in favor of Unity DE. So I'm biased :p

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix GNOME is very much like Unity... or can be made to act very much like Unity... and it's the future... so you should stick with it a little longer... or get stuck in ancient history :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :D

As it was the quickest option, I first tried switching to use onboard graphics instead of nVidia's GPU - this stops the problem i was having, at least if left for a few seconds in sleep mode (have still to see what happens when left a few hours).

Out of curiosity I'm now also trying to update the nVidia driver to the latest one (recommended version anyway). I was using version 396.54, now installing 415.27.

Will come back again once have rebooted to see if upgrading the driver fixed it too :), plus after leaving it a few hours in sleep mode.

Comment: I've made an workaround that reloads Gnome on wakeup: https://askubuntu.com/a/1454105/28997