# Weird screen after coming back from sleep

Tags: suspend, hibernate, desktop-background

When I awake Ubuntu 19.04 from sleep, the wallpaper looks very weird. As if it was corrupted or something like that.
I can change wallpapers normally on settings, and it will be back to normal. But as soon as come back from suspended mode, it becomes weird again.

[image: Wallpaper after returning from sleep]

Comment: Probably a video driver problem. Open `Software & Updates` app, `Additional Drivers` tab, and tell me what you see. What video card make/model do you have installed? What video driver version?

Comment: I'm using Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-418 (open source) and I have a gtx 760 installed. When I upgraded to 19.04 from 18.10, I didn't reinstall drivers or did anything like that.

Comment: I'd reinstall Nvidia 418, or go to their web site and grab the 430 beta. Report back.

Comment: So many problems I've read last few weeks on `418`. I'm using `384` with my GTX 970M (newer than yours) with no problem. You should try version 384 too. At the very least people with problems on `418` reported success with `396` and `390` so you could try them. Remember bigger more bloated drivers to support newer cards than yours and mine doesn't always mean better and faster for us...

Comment: @heynnema Guess you'd want to read this too ^^^

Comment: @heynnema, I installed the 430 beta, but the same thing happens with the screen.

Comment: As @WinEunuuchs2Unix suggests, maybe the older 390 drivers would work better. You could uninstall the 430 drivers, then go to `Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers` tab, and I think you'll find 390 there.

Comment: I tried this other versions... doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: Lets do 2 things. Check your BIOS version `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturor's web site to check for a newer version. Check your memory, go to https://memtest86.com and download the free memtest. Run memtest for 4/4 passes. Report back.

Comment: I've made an workaround that reloads Gnome on wakeup: https://askubuntu.com/a/1454105/28997