# Broken graphics after sleep or suspend

Tags: graphics, suspend

I don't know how exactly describe this, but here is a picture:

[image: screenshot]

Sometimes it gets even worse than this.

edit: 
back in Gnome I pressed Ctrl + F2 and in the input that showed up I entered r and fixed graphics 
but now I have kde and I don't know any temp solution like that 
here is the output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3d|vga'` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
--
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GM108M [GeForce 840M]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Does immediately suspending and resuming again fix it?

Comment: no unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

What are the specifications of your computer? Usually, graphic type and drivers take a play on that. *common with Nvidia graphics cards*.

Do run `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3d|vga'` on terminal and add the output to your request.

Also if u have an external display connected, try disconnecting before opening lid or turning on.
You can equally check out [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043398/broken-desktop-background-on-ubuntu-18-04-under-gnome-after-waking-up-from-suspe) [links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode/896544#896544) for help