# Display issues(Snow) waking from suspend Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

I just installed 19.10 on my Dell Latitude-E6510.  I used the typical file system, not the new one.  Everything seems okay except when I close the lid and open later the entire screen is filled with snow.  The cursor moves and the snow changes during any activity but i cannot see anything legible.  I have to power down via button to use again.  I have tried the proprietary Nvidia binary driver and get the same result.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a known bug but I don't have the link on phone now.

Comment: I've made an workaround that reloads Gnome on wakeup: https://askubuntu.com/a/1454105/28997

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been reported in launchpad where you can subscribe to it (and similar) bugs:

- [Ubuntu 19.04 Background and lockscreen image turns into white noise after sleep and wakeup](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1827314)

It's actually part of a larger bug affecting even more people:

- [[nvidia] Corrupted wallpaper after resuming from suspend or hibernation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1809407)