# Why do I get broken pixels when unlocking lockscreen?

Tags: screen, lock-screen, 19.04

Broken Pixels?

[image: Broken Pixels?]

as you can see on the image,the background has these strange colors. My standard lock-screen **background is plain black**, but after closing my laptop and reopening it, i get this **bizarre pattern**. It also happens on open windows, for example when I let my Document Viewer application open, the pattern appears on that window as well.

This really **only happens after locking the screen once** and it doesn't disappear until I restart/Shutdown my laptop.

Does anyone know why this phenomenon happens and how to fix it?

Comment: it's probably not what you are looking for, for an answer but I'm having the same issue as you and the only "solution" I have found so far is this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/605847/wallpaper-turns-into-distorted-pixels-after-suspend I noticed one thing on the post mentioned: that it was a Lenovo machine. I do also have a Lenovo T470p what machine are you using?

Comment: Hello, I don't have that problem anymore. Had a problem with the partitions on my ssd which corrupted ubuntu and windows, so I had to reinstall both, since then I dont have this problem. I am using an asus rog gl753vd.